# Значение слова "кулак"

Tags: значение-слов

Многие говорят, что слово "кулак" имеет славянские корни. А не является ли значение слова "кулак" вторичным, так сказать, "продуктом" татарского происхождения? Ведь окончание на "ак".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"-ак" - Это не окончание. 
Это либо суффикс, вполне русский (пятак, дурак), либо, в современном (синхронистическом) толковании - часть корня.

А вот что качается происхождения, то тюркскакая версия присутствует наряду с праиндоевропейской.

кулак
Происходит от праслав. формы, от которой в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск.    кулакъ, Никон. летоп.), русск., укр., белор. кула́к, чешск. диал. kulák «круглый   камень». Восходит к праиндоевр. *kou-l «гнуть, скрючивать». По др. гипотезе, из    тюркск., ср.: тур. kol «рука»  
(Фасмер)

//------------------

> почему во времена НЭПА зажиточных крестьян "кто-то" и "почему-то" назвал "кулаками".

Агащазз. "Во время НЭПА".
Крепкого хозяйственника называли кулаком гораздо раньше. Я думаю, сразу после отмены крепостного права. А еще раньше Чичиков так обозвал Собакевича. По аналогичным мотивам, хотя и не абсолютно.

Comment: Мне кажется, Вы немного путаете классическую прозу и историю. Да, крестьяне получили "вольную", но что они реально могли сделать? Земля по прежнему принадлежала помещику. Продать практически нечего, да и некому. Тут не то, что "кулаку", "гульке" негде появиться. :-)

Comment: @mikka66, ещё до освобождения крестьян были крепостные богаче своих помещиков, но тут не об этом. Кулаки - это зажиточные крестьяне, пользующиеся наёмным трудом (крестьяне-работодатели), а также занятые в сфере перепродажи готового сельхозтовара, ростовщичества, посредничества. На начало XX века таких хозяйств в России было до 20% от общего числа крестьянских двооров.

Comment: >Мне кажется, Вы немного путаете классическую прозу и историю.  
  
Ничуть. Я даже не думал о истории - о том, что Марк Из говорил. Это все обсуждаемо, но в данном разговоре - избыточно. Я рассуждаю с прямотой Павлика Морозова.  
Есть фиксация слова в сходном значении задолго до революции. Почему я не могу предположить распространение его в новых реалиях но вновь возникшее понятие, весьма, как сказал, близкое исходному?

Comment: "Есть фиксация слова в сходном значении задолго до революции" - с этим я согласен. Вы меня почти убедили. Спасибо за дискуссию. А вот утверждение того, что были крепостные крестьяне богаче своих помещиков, меня, мягко говоря, удивило... "Марк Из", мы точно говорим о КРЕСТЬЯНАХ, а не о "душеприказчиках"? Что, есть конкретные факты?

Comment: @mikka66, крепостные вовсе не обязательно вели крестьянское хозяйство, зачастую помещик их отпускал на подработки, главное чтоб оброк платили. На этих подработках особо энергичные крестьяне порой делали себе миллионные состояния, но выкупить себя при этом не имели возможности. Подробнее можете прочитать по ссылке http://www.agitclub.ru/hist/old/peterburg04.htm

Это всё правда касается уже позднего крепостничества.

Comment: Марк Из, спасибо.

Answer (score 6):

На -ак =-як- часто оканчиваются и славянские слова
(моряк, рыбак, земляк, пермяк, сибиряк, вожак, чудак, лешак, гусак и т.п.)
Версия тюркского происхождения, конечно, есть,отбрасывать её нельзя,Лев Успенский её поддерживает, но мне больше нравится версия общеслав., по которой КУЛАК образовалось от той же праславянской основы, что kuliti "сжимать в комок" < "гнуть, сжимать",( кукиш -исходный корень — ку- < *kou-). Эта же основа у слова культя)kul - и рука, и нога - кость конечности. Для понятия рука было слово пясть. Потом появилось кулак - согнутая пясть.

Расхожая словообраз. модель: от глагола КУЛИТЬ-сжимать + суфф -АК- = сущ. "кулак"со значением предмета, характеризующегося признаком или действием: Ср. теса́к, лежа́к, пята́к, реза́к, черпа́к, четверта́к, ветря́к, железя́ка, костя́к, кося́к, кругля́к, медя́к, пустя́к, сквозня́к, сорня́к, стоя́к и т.п.).

Зачем искать заимствование, если возможно объяснить общеславянское происхождение слова? Впрочем, мы с Вами ничего не докажем, большие учёные друг другу не доказали, так и остались каждый при своём мнении

Comment: Людмила, вообще-то версию тюркского заимствования приводит Фасмер наряду с основной, праславяснкой. И ей не ищут, она лежит на поверхности. Если уж она "такая нетакая", то её надо опровергать, а не отмахиваться.

Comment: Меня печалят и тревожат постоянные попытки найти тюркские корни у русских слов. Возможно, это идейное?

Comment: А меня беспокоит, сколько вы еще мультов себе сделаете дабы самому себе плюсики шлепать. Кстати, ALEXIN с дружественного форума - это не Вы?
Стиль весьма похож, только его тут почему-то еще нету.

Comment: Если вы это мне, то я а) не мульт (на этом ресурсе у меня нет иных аккаунтов) и б) не ALEXIN (из дружественных ресурсов я зарегистрирован лишь на Грамота.ру).

Comment: >не мульт (на этом ресурсе у меня нет иных аккаунтов)   
  
Верую, ибо абсурдно.

Comment: Прикольно читать Ваши "перепалки". Спасибо всем за ваши ответы, хотя и не однозначные. Хочу успокоить "Пересвет". Я не ищу тюркские корни у русских слов, просто в дискуссии о раскулачивании, возник спор на тему: "почему во времена НЭПА зажиточных крестьян "кто-то" и "почему-то" назвал "кулаками". Если мне не изменяет память "кулаки" "начинались" первыми и "заканчивались" последними на Кубани. А Кубань это "этническая смесь" народов проживающих и проживавших ранее на этой территории. Вот я и подумал: "Возможно, в слово "кулак", было изначально вложено не понятие кулак-рука, а нечто другое..."

Comment: >почему во времена НЭПА зажиточных крестьян "кто-то" и "почему-то" назвал "кулаками".

Ответил в тексте.
На перепалки не ведитесь. Это местное.

Comment: **mikka66**, мой ник представляет из себя русское имя. Его можно склонять :) Я рад, что мои опасения не оправдались.

Answer (score 2):

Напомню, что существует еще и слово "куль" (мешок, а может и "совокупность"). Можно предположить, что кулак ("тесно расположенные пальцы") вполне может происходить и от этого слова.

Comment: Я не стал встревать с кулями, кульками и культями, колами (палками-шестами) и колбасами. Но кулебяка!! Это такой мешок из теста с разнообразной вкусной начинкой, да.

Comment: >Но кулебяка!! Это такой мешок из теста с разнообразной вкусной начинкой, да.

Хорошо, допустим *мешок из теста* -- это *куль*. А *разнообразная вкусная начинка* -- что же, *бяка*, получается?! :-)

Comment: Про кулебяку:   
http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/3868

Еще есть версия о финских корнях.

Answer (score 0):

Смысловое значение слова <<**КУЛАК**>> легко определяется по **"Полному церковно-славянскому словарю"** магистра Гр. Дьяченко . Откроем его на стр. 1029 в *Прибавленiи* к букве **К** и увидим там слово <<**КУЛЯ**>> со значениями 1.**шар** ; 2.**ядро** ; 3. **пуля** , - интернет ссылка [ПЦСС стр. 1029 - КУЛЯ](http://www.slavdict.narod.ru/_1029.htm) . То есть , имеется ввиду предмет шарообразной , круглой формы . Что касается *пули* , то старинные пули гладкоствольной эпохи имели именно такую форму - маленьких шариков , - это смысловое значение сохранилось и в украiнской мове : русск. ПУЛЯ = укр. КУЛЯ . Таким образом , в слове <<**КУЛАК**>> содержится указание на округлую , шарообразную форму , каковую кисть руки при сжатии пальцев , в сущности , и имеет . ========================================================================== [image: ПЦСС - КУЛЯ .] =========================================================================== А теперь немножко поговорим про <<**КУЛАЧНЫЙ БОЙ**>> . Есть старинное русское слово <<**ПЯСТЬ**>> . Тот же источник , - ПЦСС на стр.531 , - поясняет что это **кисть руки , ладонь , кулак** (инт/ссылка [ПЦСС стр.531 ПЯСТЬ](http://www.slavdict.narod.ru/_0531.htm)) =========================================================================== [image: ПЦСС ПЯСТЬ] =========================================================================== Отсюда словосочетание <<**РУКОПАШНЫЙ БОЙ**>> , то есть бой невооруженными (*голыми* ) руками . ... ПЯСТНЫЙ переходит в ... ПАШНЫЙ , т. к. **СТ**/**ШТ** = **Щ** , а **Щ** легко трансформируется в **Ш** . Позднее , после появления огнестрельного оружия , это словосочетание приобрело расширительный смысл : бой любым холодным оружием (не огнестрельным) , - штык , приклад , тесак , нож , саперная лопатка , каска , -  а также *голыми руками*  , - удары кулаком , ногой , захваты и т. п . Теперь берёмся за <<**КУЛАЧНЫЙ БОЙ**>> . В древнерусской истории упоминания о нём связаны с Новгородом Великим . Былина о Василии Буслаеве повествует о массовой драке , учинённой им в Новгороде . А вот летописный источник , относящийся к киевскому князю Мстиславу IV-му . Перед битвой он спрашивает бойцов новгородского (именно , новгородского !) отряда , как они желают биться - *пешими или на конях* ? И новгородцы дружно отвечают киевлянину : "*Мы не хотим на конях , но по примеру предков наших пеши и* **на кулачках** *биться* ." И здесь возникает вопрос : неужели эти новгородцы в войске Мстислава IV-го были такие самоотверженные психи , что идут на противника с одними кулаками ?! - а противник-то , поди , при оружии и в доспехах ?! И тут является догадка - а что значит "**на кулачках**" ? что называется **кулачками** ? При этом , та же летопись сообщает , что новгородцы , перед тем , как броситься на врага ,  "*вскричав , подняли* **кии**" . И , если напрячь соображаловку , то можно понять , что <<КУЛАЧКИ>> тут (и с ударением , скорее всего , на втором слоге , а не на последнем) это не кулаки в современном понимании , а то же , что и *булавы* . Булава это холодное металлическое оружие в форме оснащённого острыми шипами  шара , надетого на рукоятку , то бишь , - **кий**  (у столяров большой молоток с деревянной головкой и по сей день  называется *киянкой*) ; по смыслу , от того же церковно-славянского <<**КУЛЯ**>> , иначе , - **ШАР** . Да и по содержанию былины о Василии Буслаеве не совсем понятно , как там , в Новгороде , бьются участники драки : упоминаются "*дубины вязовые*" и "*булавами буйны головы пробиваны*" . Напрашивается ВЫВОД : первоначально слово <<**КУЛАК** / **КУЛАЧКА**>> означало *палку с шаром на конце* .  Для состязаний и внутриместных потасовок использовались деревянные **кул**-**А**-**чки** , типа усовершенствованной дубины , а в военно-боевых целях применялись металлические **кул**-**А**-**чки** , которые более известны как **булавы** . //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Это подтверждают и историческая информация , относящаяся к Новгороду . Ещё во времена язычества там стоял на почётном месте идол Перуна с , державший в руках тяжёлую палицу с оловянным навершием . Когда в Новгород пришли христиане , они сбросили этого идола в Волхов . Легенда повествует , что проплывая под Великим мостом , перунов идол бросил на мост свою палицу и вскричал : "*Вот , что вам , новгородцы , в память мою оставляю ! Поминайте меня и бейтесь , безумные , на этом мосту !*"  И , как отмечают исследователи , у новгородцев на долгое-долгое время вошло в обычай в праздники , вместо других увеселений , биться всяким дрекольем в честь древнего бога Перуна , в частности у этого же моста . В одной из новгородских церквей и по сей день хранится целый набор всякого дубья (или "перуновых палиц") , судя по всему , конфискованного у любителей этой языческой забавы . То есть : палками бились новгородцы , а не кулаками боксировали . //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  И тот <<**КУЛАЧНЫЙ БОЙ**>> , о котором рассказывает былина "Про Василия Буслаева" представлял из себя бой **деревянными булвами** /= **кулаками** , **кулачками** / , а уж потом это словосочетание перешло на состязания типа боксёрских , в силу схожести руки со сжатыми в КУЛЮ-шар пальцами с КУЛЕ-образной булавой . А собственно знаменитый русский КУЛАЧНЫЙ БОЙ , как искусство ударов голыми руками , сродни первоначальному АНГЛИЙСКОМУ БОКСУ , на Руси появился не в Новгороде , а в Москве . Его привили в народе опричники Ивана Грозного , которых царь выпускал на лёд Москвы-реки устраивать кулачно-боксерские состязания . ========================================================================== P.S. Где мой главный оппонент **@behemothus** ?! Что он скажет на сей раз ?!